# Show/Hide dropdown menu based on previous selection

Tags: javascript, python, django

I would like to show an additional dropdown menu based on a user's selection. Using my case, if a user selects installments an additional dropdown menu would appear, it would then be hidden if the user changes its selection.

This is what I have tried

```
            <select name='installments' required class="form-control my-2" onclick="choose()">
                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>How would you like to pay?</option>
                {% for value, name in form.fields.installments.choices %}
                    <option value="{{value}}">{{name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <!-- if installments -->
            <select name='installnum' class="form-control my-2" style="display:none">
                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>How many months would you like to pay this over?</option>
                {% for value, name in form.fields.installmnum.choices %}
                    <option value="{{value}}">{{name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
```

This is the javascript I wrote

```
<script>
    function choose() {
        if (document.getElementById('installments').value == 'installments') {
            document.getElementById('installnum').style.display == 'block';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('installnum').style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
</script>
```

The idea is supposed to be if you select installments the dropdown menu installnum would appear

This is my forms.py with the list of options for each dropdown menu

```
installment_choices = (
    ('upfront', 'Upfront'),
    ('installments', 'Installments'),
)
installnum_choices = (
    ('2', '2 months'),
    ('3', '3 months'),
    ('4', '4 months'),
    ('5', '5 months'),
    ('6', '6 months'),
    ('7', '7 months'),
    ('8', '8 months'),
    ('9', '9 months'),
    ('10', '10 months'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this answers the question, but it looks like you're trying to access the DOM element and read it's value directly. I believe you need to look at the value generated by the event.

```
function choose (event)
{
   event.preventDefault();
   if(event.value === "expected") { // ... then modify the css }
}
```

Comment: Ok, first thing I noticed is that you bound your eventListener to the html onClick attribute. That is something I have only seen by another Python person. But, I think it would be better to do it in JavaScript. Like const installmentsSelector = document.getElementById("installments"). Then you would bind the event listener: installmentsSelector.addEventListener(click, choices). When your event is generated by the web-browser as a result of the user click, an event object is passed to your callback. You can call it whatever you want, but you need to read the value from the event.

Comment: the event.preventdefault() in the snippet I gave you prevents the browser from doing a page refresh. I think that may only be needed for a Single Page App when doing a submit. But I think you may get the idea.

Comment: You know, now that I look closer, there might be a bug. It seems you are comparing instead of assigning. In JavaScript == returns a boolean. You really meant =. document.getElementById('installnum').style.display == 'block';